# Game programming in C, where do I get started?

Tags: c

I started programming about 6 months back and have a decent knowledge in how to code in C. I have mainly used it to implement elementary algorithms or solve Project Euler questions (reached 50 now :) ) 
What I really want to learn since a long time is game programming. Ie make simple 2D games like snake, or pocket tanks. By simple, I no way mean the amount of work or effort it's going to take to make these games

I've tried searching the net but have had no luck with that. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

What exactly will I need to learn? Where do I start?

Comment: this is more suited to the gamedev site: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: try googling on Beginning game programming.   You're probably going to have to make the leap to c++ but it shouldn't be too big of a stretch

Comment: Check out the [Game Programming Wiki](http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/Main_Page) on where to get started.

Comment: Heh, funny thing about that leap to C++.. For that ultra high performance code in game titles I've worked on, C++ still ends up going out the window for the most part.. It ends up being C with some C++isms.

Answer (score 3):

Game Programming requires a lot of Computer Science stuff on top of creativity. By Computer Science stuff I mean Algorithms, Data Structures, Computer Architecture, Computer Graphics, Operating System Internals, Artificial Intelligence & at least basic familiarity with Mathematics & Physics + experience on playing Games + Passion for Games. As you seem to be a good Algorithmic coder (Coding problems on Project Euler) so it should not be very difficult for you.

Now coming to your question one simple way to start is: Microsoft XNA (which lets you just go into game programming without having too much knowledge on above areas, ofcourse having it will be an advantage for you in longer run). Check it out: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_XNA

You can also check out this book: [http://www.amazon.com/Beginning-Game-Programming-Michael-Morrison/dp/0672326590/ref=pd_sim_b_4](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672326590)

I have read the above (It's in C/C++/Win32) and it is really a good resource on implementing basic games which will give you a very good start to jump to XNA as a next step.

Comment: Don't forget AI, AI is important too.  Especially efficient realtime pathfinding.  At least for most games.

Comment: @sr2222: Absolutely. Your comment gave a smile on my face as I work on Machine Learning stuff in Search domain so how can I have forgotten AI which is really really important in Gameing. +1 for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

You could go with `graphics.h`. I am saying this because, when I were in your stage, I began with **Worm and nibbles** game, a very easy game, which can be constructed with `drawPoly` function. I used drawPoly as my implementation, but you could use you won. 
In addition to that, `graphics.h` will provide many user-defined functions, to draw lines,rectangles,polygens. It also provide functions to color them in many different ways. 
So, When you want to start gaming in C, I would suggest `graphics.h` as a good starting point.